# For which values of $n$ does the following inequality stand?

Tags: calculus, inequality

For which values of $n$, does it stand that:

$$-3n^4\log^2 n \geq -3 n^4 \sqrt{n} \quad ?$$

Comment: There’s an obvious simplification to make the inequality much simpler; do you see what it is?

Comment: Is $n$ a natural, integer or real number?

Comment: $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: @evinda I temporarily deleted my answer to improve some of the numerical estimates, but it's back now and complete. Sorry for any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: Do you mean log base 10 or the natural log?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Welcome back! You're gonna give André a run for his money, now that he hasn't got a 10-month head start.

Comment: @alexqwx: Thanks! I probably won’t be quite so active this time, though.

Answer (score 1):

Doing the easy cancellations for the $-3n^4$ factors you get the equivalent statement

> $$\log^2n\le \sqrt n$$

i.e. $4\log\log n\le \log n$

setting $x=\log n$ we have $4\log x\le x$ i.e. ${x\over\log x}\ge 4$. But this function is always increasing  since the derivative of ${x\over\log x}$ is just ${\log x-1\over\log^2 x}>0$ for every $x>e$, i.e. every natural number, $n$, greater than $e^e\approx 15$, so just testing some values gives $x\approx 8.6135$ so then $e^{8.6135}\approx 5505\approx n$.

If you're looking for the smallest, there's some poking around to be done, since this is not exact, and the value is gotten by testing some values for ${x\over\log x}$, but doing it for $x=8.6135$ gets accuracy to three decimal places (for $x$), and poking around, one sees that $5504$ works and $5503$ does not, so $5504$ is the smallest.

---

As Daniel notes, the above discussion is when it is true forevermore, i.e. after that point we're going to see this inequality hold. For specific values **less than** $e^e$, i.e. $n\le 15$ we can just test directly and it turns out the inequality holds for $n\in \{1,2, 3, 4\}$ as well.

Comment: $n \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ works too.

Comment: Right, I should mention that. Thanks @DanielFischer